# How to remove some fields from core Joomla Profile Editor?

Tags: user

How to remove these un-necessary fields from Joomla front-end Profile editor

**Editor**

**Timezone**

**Front-end language**

Also, i want to know is it possible to remove the password changing fields from the Core Joomla profile editor? I want to make a separate page for Password Changing stuff for the front-end users?

Comment: This does not remove the "Personal Details" on the frontend user profile editor page. I have tried commenting out the code and cannot get it to go away. Using the options settings and setting the Frontend User Parameters only removes the section below the Personal details section. Does anyone have a different solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Joomla backend, go to:

**Users** >> **User Manager** >> **Options**

Then set **Frontend User Parameters** to **hide**

Hope this helps

As for the password changing fields, I think this should be asked as a different question

Comment: I have checked that already! There's no option of hiding these three parameters?

Comment: what version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: hahah! i was just kidding! It worked! (again)

Comment: I was getting a little worried there lol. Glad it works

Comment: Password Changing Fields Question : http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/962/separate-password-changing-form-for-the-joomla-front-end-users

Comment: This does not remove the "Personal Details" on the frontend user profile editor page. I have tried commenting out the code and cannot get it to go away. Using the options settings and setting the Frontend User Parameters only removes the section below the Personal details section. Does anyone have a different solution?-posted on behalf of @tbro