# Separate Password Changing Form for the Joomla Front-end users?

Tags: component

I want to know is it possible to remove the password changing fields from the Core Joomla profile editor? I want to make a separate page for Password Changing stuff for the front-end users?

Answer (score 3):

You can quite easily override how the core pages are displayed using your templates folder.  See [How to override the output from the Joomla! core](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) for details.   In short, you make a copy of the core form in your template/html folder and modify that copy to your liking.  If Joomla finds the form there, it will use that one instead of the installed version.

Comment: can you tell me exactly which file renders the Profile Edit page?

Comment: I believe that it's edit.php located in  \components\com_users\views\profile\tmpl\ .  The override to to create would located in YourTemplateFolder\html\com_users\profile