# Remove two factor authentication fields from core Joomla profile editor

Tags: user, profile

I'd like not to show the Two Factor Authentication Fields and One time emergency passwords section from the core profile editing page.

Is there a simple solution similar to this question [How to remove some fields from core Joomla Profile Editor?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/960/how-to-remove-some-fields-from-core-joomla-profile-editor)?

Answer (score 3):

You only need to disable the two factor authentication plugin from Plugin Manager > (search for) Two Factor > Disable the Two factor Authentication plugin which is enabled. That should be it!

If you DO NOT have access to the Administrator / Administration panel of the website because you have enabled 2FA and you know you can't login, you'll need to disable it via PHPMyAdmin

1. Log in to PHPmyadmin
2. Find the table ending in  '_extensions' (the first few digits/letters are vary by installation)
3. Find the plugin named plg_twofactorauth_totp
4. change its 'enabled' status from '1'to '0' and save!

This disables the 2FA plugin

The 2FA plugin controls the 2FA fields, once it's disabled the fields will be gone. (note: if your using a 3rd party plugin for 2FA or for login that includes 2FA you will need to handle those on a case by case scenario)

If you want to set your 2FA for just front end or just back end (or even both) then follow these steps

The first step you need to do is enable two factor authentication by enabling the plugin from the Plugin Manager (Plugin Manager > Two Factor Authentication - Yubikey or Google Authenticator (depends which key generator you plan to use)). You can select whether you want this to be enabled for

The back-end only (admistrator)
The front-end only (front-end)
Both

Solution from https://www.dart-creations.com/joomla/joomla-tutorials/enabling-and-using-joomla-two-factor-authentication.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I guess it means that I can't remove 2FA only for some users? I was intending to keep it for super users. All I really want to do is remove the fields from the password reset form.

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered that both the Google and YubiKey authentication plugins have an option to select using 2FA for either frontend, backend or both. By setting both of these to 'backend only' hides the secret key field at login and all 2FA related fields in the user profile update screen. 2FA is still enabled when trying to access the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not want to show this information - allowing users to apply two factor security can drastically decrease your chance of your site being hacked through brute forced passwords.

I would be looking to do the opposite and actually ENFORE every user to use two factor security

In removing this, you are decreasing the security of your user accounts.

Comment: -1 While I agree with your sentiment, it doesn't answer the user's question. It's better suited as a comment.

Comment: We understand the risk but for this particular time limited project with our specific users we don't want to use two factor authentication

Comment: have you tried just disabling the 2 factor plugin? I suspect that'll do it.

Comment: @BrianPeat Nope that doesn't do it

Comment: bummer. What about this? It might hide too much though. http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/960/how-to-remove-some-fields-from-core-joomla-profile-editor

Comment: Cant believe you voted me down for highlighting the best practice security and for encouraging sites to be be more secure. Even a "time limited project with our specific users" can still be hacked, and should still provide best practice when it comes to security - there is simply no reason, no excuse for dumbing down.

Comment: @BrianPeat Thanks for the link. I'd already done all that but the 2FA fields remain.

Answer (score -1):

just rename 'twofactorauth' folder from cpanel >. File manager >> plugins